# Python Subprocess how to pass subshell argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, subprocess

I am doing a script using **SoX** to merge multiple audio file together.

This command works in the terminal

```
sox &(ls *.mp3) out.mp3
```

but if I try using it inside a python script by calling subprocess.run() it doesn't

```
subprocess.run(['sox', '$(ls *.mp3)', 'out.mp3'])

> sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `$(ls *.mp3)': No such file or
> directory
```

I image that is because of the subshell operation, but I don't know how to pass it correctly. 
I also tried, as some other post suggested, passing the argument `shell=True` but then it says

```
> sox FAIL sox: Not enough input filenames specified
```

I am in the same working directory and I also tried supplying the full path but doesn't work either.
I could just write a bash script and call it, but I would like to know how to deal in this scenario with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to use `shell=True` to force `subprocess` to run your command through the shell interpreter and parse the wildcards/sub-commands. However this (depending on the platform) imposes that the argument is passed *as string*, not as list of parameters. A lot of constraints for a lazy & unsafe way of doing it.

Wait. You can do *without* `shell=True` using `glob.glob`:

```
subprocess.run(['sox'] + glob.glob('*.mp3') + ['out.mp3'])
```

Would be better to check if there actually *are* `mp3` files in the current folder so:

```
input_files = glob.glob('*.mp3')
if input_files:
   subprocess.run(['sox'] + input_files + ['out.mp3'])
else:
    raise Exception("No mp3 files")
```

if you get the `"No mp3 files"` message, then check the current directory. It's always good to use a parameter for the input directory, and avoid relying on the current directory (`glob.glob(os.path.join(input_directory,'*.mp3'))`)

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your first point of using `shell=True` because when I did, I had the same error of `> sox FAIL sox: Not enough input filenames specified`. However without it works perfectly.